# Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. Threads en servicio windows c#

Tags: c#, .net, servicio

tengo tres hilos que ejecuto en un servicio windows, cada hilo realiza una consulta  a la BD

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer.Interval = 100;
    myTimer.Elapsed += myTimer_Elapsed;
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.Start();
}


void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    myTimer.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        Thread Hilo25 = new Thread(Transacciones);
        Hilo25.Start();

        Thread libRep = new Thread(TransaccionesCEP);
        libRep.Start();

        Thread estadoT = new Thread(statusT);
        estadoT.Start(); 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Log2("ERROR INICIO DEL SERVICIO: " + ex.ToString());
    }

    myTimer.Start();
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

el problema es que solo se ejecuta un hilo y los otros me genera una excepcion de 
  :ERROR INICIO DEL SERVICIO:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Se produjo una excepción de tipo
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

cuando ejecuto un solo hilo a la vez esta funcionando sin ningun problema por lo que no se si me falta configurar algo

Comment: Me late que los hilos tratan de acceder a los mismos recursos, no se libera la memoria correctamente, colapsa y por ello se cae el servicio.

Comment: @fredyfx yo tambien pienso que eso pasa, pero como podria hacer para liberar memoria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas poniendo un `interval` de 100, recuerda que son milisegundos, o sea cada 0,1seg estas lanzando el evento

Recomendaria que subas ese valor, no se, digamos 5000, para que sea al menos cada 5seg

[Timer.Interval](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=netframework-4.8)